# Generating function of gamma quotient.

Tags: generating-functions, gamma-function

I would like to show that the following is true. Let $g=\sum_i a_i x^i$ with 
$$
a_i=C\frac{\Gamma (i+0.5)}{\Gamma(i+2)}
$$
and normalisation constant obtained from $\sum_i a_i=1$. Given this we should have
$$
g=\frac 1{1+\sqrt{1-x}}
$$
I have no intuition on how to approach this and would welcome any hints or advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\Gamma(n+1/2)}{\Gamma(n+2)}x^n
&=\frac{1}{\Gamma(3/2)}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n\mathrm{B}\left(n+\frac12,\frac32\right)
\\\color{gray}{[\text{integral representation of }\mathrm{B}]}\quad
&=\frac{2}{\sqrt\pi}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n\int_0^1y^{n-1/2}(1-y)^{1/2}~dy
\\\color{gray}{[\textstyle\sum\leftrightarrow\int\text{ and geometric series}]}\quad
&=\frac{2}{\sqrt\pi}\int_0^1\sqrt\frac{1-y}{y}\frac{dy}{1-xy}
\\\color{gray}{[\text{substitution }\sqrt{(1-y)/y}=z]}\quad
&=\frac{4}{\sqrt\pi}\int_0^\infty\frac{z^2~dz}{(1+z^2)(1-x+z^2)}
\\\color{gray}{[\text{partial fractions}]}\quad
&=\frac{4}{x\sqrt\pi}\int_0^\infty\left(\frac{1}{1+z^2}-\frac{1-x}{1-x+z^2}
\right)dz
\\\color{gray}{[\text{elementary integrals}]}\quad
&=\frac{2\sqrt\pi}{x}(1-\sqrt{1-x})=\color{blue}{\frac{2\sqrt\pi}{1+\sqrt{1-x}}}.
\end{align}

Comment: (One could also recognize an instance of the [binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series) right away.)