# Double sum of a triple-product of binomial coefficients geometric series

Tags: binomial-coefficients, geometric-series, catalan-numbers

My main challenge is to perform the double summation,

$$\sum\limits_{\substack{i+j\geq2\\ i+j \text{ even}\\i,j\geq0}}\binom{-5/2}{i}\binom{i+j}{(i+j)/2-1}\binom{1/2}{j}x^{i+j}$$

Letting $i+j=2k: k\geq1,i,j\geq0$, the summation splits into,

$$\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\infty}\binom{-5/2}{i}\sum\limits_{k=\lceil \frac{i+1}{2}\rceil}^{\infty}\binom{2k}{k-1}\binom{1/2}{2k-i}x^{2k}\\=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\infty}\binom{-5/2}{i}(-1)^{1-i}2^{i+1}\sum\limits_{k=\lceil \frac{i+1}{2}\rceil}^{\infty}kC_{2k-i-1}C_ky^{2k}$$

where $y=x/4$ and $C_k$ is the $k^{th}$ Catalan number
$$C_k = \frac{1}{k+1}\binom{2k}{k}.$$

I have had little luck trying to perform the sum $$\sum\limits_{k=\lceil \frac{i+1}{2}\rceil}^{\infty}kC_{2k-i-1}C_ky^{2k}$$  I have tried using the Catalan number generating function to no avail.  The generating function, $C(x)$, being,
$$C(x) = \frac{2}{1+\sqrt{1-4x}}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}C_nx^n$$

Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can get displayed equations by enclosing them in double instead of single dollar signs. (This is particularly relevant for legibility if you have summations with multiple lines of limits, exponents, subscripts and fractions.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of $i+j=2k$ is good with the inner summation over $i$: the given sum is $$F(x):=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\binom{2k}{k-1}x^{2k}\sum_{i=0}^{2k}\binom{-5/2}{i}\binom{1/2}{2k-i},$$ and the inner sum is $\binom{-2}{2k}=2k+1$ by the [Chu-Vandermonde identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity#Chu%E2%80%93Vandermonde_identity). Hence, $$F(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(2k+1)\binom{2k}{k-1}x^{2k}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k\binom{2k+1}{k}x^{2k}=x^2 G'(x^2),$$ where $$G(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{2k+1}{k}x^k=\frac{1}{2x}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x}}-1\right)$$ is computed [like this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3566670), or by recognizing the binomial series, or another way known to you.

Comment: Beautiful stuff.  Thanks a lot.  I still need to check your generating function but everything looks good over the first glance.  Cheers!